# How to upgrade process template for team project in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I have been responsible for administrate our TFS projects and have started to investigate the current configurations. I found the following link for determining which process our team projects are connected to: [How to determine what Process template an existing TFS 2012 project is configured with?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dcdfd855-4cf7-4a1a-90cd-1189bee739b5/how-to-determine-what-process-template-an-existing-tfs-2012-project-is-configured-with?forum=tfsprocess)

When using the rest API described in the article above, it seems like the projects depend on a process template called "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013". When reading this article: [Scrum process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/scrum-process?view=vsts) it seems to me that the process is outdated and should be upgraded to use the "Scrum" template.

I have searched the internet for knowledge on how to upgrade the project to use the new Scrum process but had no luck of finding an answer. Does anyone have an idea of how to update the projects to depend on a newer process? Maybe the whole question is wrongly put as I may lack some obvious knowledge about how these things are meant to work. All I want is to ensure our projects are updated to use the latest TFS technology.

We use Visual Studio 2017 and did recently upgrade our TFS server to TFS 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, some new features will be introduced when upgrade from old to new version of TFS.

Generally if you haven't made any changes to the original process template, upgrading is quite easy. Just enable new features by running the [Configure Features Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx) in your team projects configuration page.

If it can’t upgrade automatically, you need to apply updates manually. See [Add updates to team projects manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-features-manually?view=vsts).

If you customized the process template, then you can follow the steps mentioned in this link to [Update a customized process template to access new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/update-customized-process-template?view=vsts).

To update the existing projects, a not so nice but easy way is to remove all work items and process data from your project and then add the newest items. [Martin Hinshelwood has some great guidance](http://nakedalm.com/do-you-know-how-to-upgrade-a-process-template-but-still-keep-your-data-intact/) on how to do this.